# Remove JInternalFrame default title bar

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

I'm trying to remove the title bar of a `JInternalFrame`, I tried this.

```
void remove_title_bar(){
        putClientProperty("JInternalFrame.isPalette", Boolean.TRUE);
        getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);
    BasicInternalFrameTitlePane titlePane =  
            (BasicInternalFrameTitlePane) ((BasicInternalFrameUI) this.getUI()).  
            getNorthPane();
        this.remove(titlePane);
        this.setBorder(null);
        //this.setUI(null); doesn't work either
    }
```

It doesn't remove the title bar, it clears it, I mean I see the title bar blank(a white rectangle at top).

How can I remove it?

Answer (score 3):

Well I found this code, and yes it works(at least for me).
Please tell me if it's not a good method.

```
    void remove_title_bar(){
        putClientProperty("JInternalFrame.isPalette", Boolean.TRUE);
        getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);
        ((BasicInternalFrameUI) this.getUI()).setNorthPane(null);
        this.setBorder(null);
    }
```

Comment: +1 but works without usage of `getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);`, as aside do you realy to want to modalWhetever, torso from JInternalFrame ???

Comment: I have to remove the title bar because the default UI isn't sync with the application theme. I know it may sound weird, but customers, weird orders, weird orders everywhere!. I have to resize, move and iconify the new frame manually. and thank you so much for your edit :D @mKorbel

Comment: did you tried some od (custom???) LookAndFeels, part (authors) of them to overide this awfull decorations

Comment: @mKorbel Yes of course, but some of them just uses the default(OS) UI for title bar, I have to decorate it as they want, poor me :D

Comment: @mKorbel Substance is good, but is heavy! also doesn't have any good documentation. and the worst part is, each new version(release) isn't compatible with last one.

Comment: each new version(release) isn't compatible with last one == tax for Java7

Comment: @mKorbel Exactly, they also changed the package names too. Substance is very rich, but is not the best. I'm just so angry why didn't I choose SWT instead of swing? really why?